# Informix JBDC hold cursors over commit

Tags: java, jdbc, cursor, informix

Using Informix 12.10FC5DE and JDBC.4.10.JC5DE, I am trying to write a Java program that will perform a "controlled" delete on a table.
The database containing the table is logged and the table has "lock mode row".
The program will receive a maximum number of rows to delete and a perform periodic commits every X rows (to limit the number of locks and prevent long transactions).

Using SPL, I can declare a cursor with hold and do a foreach loop with "delete where current of".

Using the JDBC, I can use the `resultSet` methods `.next()` and `.deleteRow()` to perform what I want (I set up the connection and statement to not autocommit or close the resultSet on commit).
It works, but it is slow (under the hood the JDBC is sending something like "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = ?").

The code I have is something similar to the following:

```
Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
conn.setHoldability(ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

String cmd = "SELECT id FROM teste_001 FOR UPDATE;";
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
stmt.setFetchSize(100);
stmt.setCursorName("myowncursor");

ResultSet resultados = stmt.executeQuery(cmd);  // Get the resulSet and cursor

int maximo = 2000;
int passo = 100;
int cTotal = 0;
int cIter = 0;

cmd2 = "DELETE FROM teste_001 WHERE CURRENT OF " +
         resultados.getCursorName();
PreparedStatement stmtDel2 = conn.prepareStatement(cmd2);

while (resultados.next())
{
    if (cIter < maximo)
    {
        int resultCode2 = stmtDel2.executeUpdate();
        if (resultCode2 == 1)
        {
            cTotal++;
        }
        cIter++;
        if ((cIter % passo) == 0)
        {
            conn.commit();  // Perform periodic commit
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;  // maximum number of rows reached 
    }
}
conn.commit();  // Perform final commit

stmtDel2.close();
resultados.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

The problem is that when I perform the 1st periodic commit, I get this error when I try the next delete:

```
java.sql.SQLException: There is no current row for UPDATE/DELETE cursor.
SQLCODE = -266 ; MESSAGE: There is no current row for UPDATE/DELETE cursor. ; SQLSTATE = 24000
```

Seems the cursor is being closed even with me setting the "HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT".

Does anyone know if what I am trying with the JDBC is possible?

EDIT:
Since informix suports de IBM DRDA protocol i configured a drda listener on my test informix instance and used DB2 UDB JDBC Universal Driver.
The code is pretty much the same, only the driver changes:

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
```

With the DRDA driver, the cursor is kept open over commits and the program behaves as expected. Tracing the session on informix instance i get this type of statement:

```
DELETE FROM test_001 WHERE CURRENT OF SQL_CURSH600C1
```

So, informix does suport "HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT" with the DRDA driver but i still cannot make it work with the "ifxDriver".

Comment: Don't issue the commit, a lot of database servers close the server-side cursor on commit, even if the JDBC side keeps the clientside cursor open due to `HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT`, in which case - usually - the rows are cached client side before the commit is performed. Also note that with a fetch size of 100 the server side cursor might be up to 99 rows ahead, which might mean that you are deleting the wrong rows.

Comment: The objective is to issue the commit. Which i can do iterating through the `resultSet` without using an for update cursor.

Comment: `HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` is - for a number of databases - implemented by a clientside trick (eg copying all rows from the cursor into a clientside cache) before performing the commit. If you want to use the server-side cursor, then with those databases you shouldn't commit until you are really done (this apparently also applies to informix based on your description).

Comment: @Mark I update my question with results from using a different driver and it seems informix does support server side `HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` . Which leaves me wondering if i am not properly using the JDBC.4.10.JC5DE driver or if it really is not supported. The documentation of the driver does not make this clear (at least, not clear for me).